# apt-get on Ubuntu gets too out-dated-software

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd

It seems the package repository for Ubuntu (apt-get) is somehow not actively updating for the new versions of packages. I didn't realize this until I tried FreeBSD's package manager. Ubuntu gives me nginx1.4.6, while FreeBSD gives me 1.8.x. I'm wondering whether this is really true or I missed something.

Comment: What versions of Ubuntu and FreeBSD are you using?

Comment: Note: I didn't downvote, but I can see the reason. Your question lacks information and details, it can hardly be called a "good" question.

Comment: `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS x64` and `FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p10`.

Comment: For new versions of software in Linux look at Debian testing. 
Or Gentoo, which packaging philosophy look like BSD.

Answer (score 3):

That's how stable distribution releases work.  They "lock" the version of the software in place, so that bugs aren't inadvertently introduced when you do a mass-upgrade to fix security vulnerabilities.

If you want to track "the latest and greatest" of everything, you'll need to modify your list of package sources to include those package repositories where the latest things are available.  That can be risky, though, due to the increase in bugs that you'll inevitably stumble across.  Typically, on production systems, you run a stable release and just run "backports" of the one or two packages that you really, really need to be newer (because you rely on features not available in the older release).

Comment: Thanks @womble. Yes, that sounds reasonable. But I suspect it might not be a matter they want to keep it stable, but they don't have a chance to catch everything up to date. For example, nginx, golang, mysql. Those versions in the apt-get repository are way too old that I don't really believe it's because they want to keep it stable.

Comment: Yes, it's because they want to keep a release stable.  Once a release is made, the packages in it are not updated except for security issues and *showstopper* bugs.  That's how stable releases work.

Comment: So do you think nginx 1.4.6 released in March of 2014 is still considered the latest stable now, and anything after March 2014 is considered not stable?

Comment: For a given stable release of a distribution, yes.  A newer distribution release may have a newer nginx version available, however.

Comment: With FreeBSD, I always get what I want, I mean relatively up to date versions of software. Does it mean Ubuntu guys are more conservative than the FreeBSD guys?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is.  Ubuntu is providing a distribution for use in environments where consistency is preferred over having the latest features; FreeBSD is providing up-to-date software, which has the risk of introducing regressions.